# i8kutils i8kmon uses wrong thresholds after resuming from suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, fan

Laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 3521. No dedicated GPU, right fan only.

I have it set to only turn on the fan at 70 C, but when I close my laptop and open it again, it starts turning on the fan at some random temperature between 53 C and 60 C. It keeps the fan running until it gets below 50 C. None of my thresholds are set like this. Restarting the i8kmon service seems to fix the problem temporarily. How do I fix this permanently?

Here's my i8kmon.conf:

```
# Sample i8kmon configuration file (/etc/i8kmon.conf, ~/.i8kmon).

# Kernel I8K status file
set config(proc_i8k) /proc/i8k

# Kernel APM status file
set config(proc_apm) /proc/apm

# Kernel ACPI status file
set config(proc_acpi) /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/0/status

# External program to control the fans
set config(i8kfan) /usr/bin/i8kfan

# Applet geometry, override with --geometry option
set config(geometry) {}

# Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon) 0

# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto) 1

# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 0

# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 5

# Temperature display unit (C/F), override with --unit option
set config(unit) C

# Temperature threshold at which the temperature is displayed in red
set config(t_high) 80

# Minimum expected fan speed

# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# These were tested on the I8000. If you have a different Dell laptop model
# you should check the BIOS temperature monitoring and set the appropriate
# thresholds here. In doubt start with low values and gradually rise them
# until the fans are not always on when the cpu is idle.
set config(0) {{- 0} -1 70 -1 70}
set config(1) {{- 0} -1 70 -1 70}
set config(2) {{- 1} 60 80 60 80}
set config(3) {{- 2} 70 128 70 128}


# end of file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. Apparently when going to sleep and resuming the i8kfan settings are not retained and control is given back to BIOS or whatever controls the fans by default. Having `i8kfan 0 0` automatically run on resume fixes the issue.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how did you do that? I have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I've since switched back to Windows, so I don't remember what I did. Look up how to run commands on resume; it's different between older and newer versions of Ubuntu. Then you just run i8kfan 0 0 on resume and the issue is solved.