# How to address Dell M6600 laptop sensor and fan speed issues

Tags: dell, fan, temperature, sensors

Does running `i8kmon`, `thermald`, and `sensors` simultaneously have known resource contention issues that cause fans to start spinning at lower temperatures than the thresholds I've configured? Is getting Dell laptop fan speeds and noise under control a solved issue?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a **Dell Precision M6600**. I'm using `i8kmon` and still get fans spinning at higher RPMs triggered at lower temperatures than the thresholds I've configured. I've read these posts and others. All solutions are temporary, at best.

- [i8kutils i8kmon uses wrong thresholds after resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715520/i8kutils-i8kmon-uses-wrong-thresholds-after-resuming-from-suspend)
- [Dell fans not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490292/dell-fans-not-working)
- [How do I get fan control working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63588/how-do-i-get-fan-control-working)

I've disabled BIOS fan control with `smm`,`[dellfan][0]`, `[dell-bios-fan-control][1]`

*Hardware Sensor Indicator*, `i8kctl` and `sensors` output all show temperatures below what should trigger any fan activity.

`i8kctl` output:
1.0 A18 J59D4S1 53 1 1 3413 3034 -1 -1

`sensors` output:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3034 RPM
Video Fan:     3410 RPM
CPU:            +53.0°C  
Ambient:        +52.0°C  
SODIMM:         +47.0°C  
SODIMM:         +47.0°C  
SODIMM:         +47.0°C  
GPU:            +62.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.68 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
```

["Hardware Sensor Indicator" output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eruoh.png)

Comment: `sensors` does not control the fans.  Have you tried stopping thermald and see if the issue persists?

Comment: With `thermald` stopped, BIOS control disabled, and `i8kmon` running, the fans spin up less frequently and at lower RPM. Fans spin up appropriately as system temperature rises, resource utilization spikes. They spin down appropriately and often back to 0 RPM which they had not been doing under BIOS control. I will keep `thermald` stopped and continue to monitor. 

I am seeing lag in UI response. I don't know how to measure / quantify this, but it's more typing, clicking, window focus lag than with BIOS control enabled.

Thanks for your time and assistance here.